# Remove tooltip from the close, minimize and maximize/restore buttons in a form's title bar

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I need to remove the tool tip from the control buttons(close, minimize, maximize/restore buttons) in the title bar of a form.

Is it possible? If possible how can I do that?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am creating a custom form by deriving it from System.Window.Forms.Form. For that I want to provide localization support for the tooltip. I have defined the tooltip for the buttons. But the default tooltip also displayed in it. So I need to remove the default tooltip from the form

Comment: _"...For that I want to provide localization support for the tooltip..."_ - I would have thought the OS would have done that?

Comment: Couple of years back i was working on dynamic forms in which i need same functionality. What i did i removed the control box by Just disable the control box on the form properties and add own buttons on the top right corner. So i can customize them as per my need.

Answer (score 0):

```
EntryPoint="SystemParametersInfoW")]
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern  bool SystemParametersInfoW(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, 
System.IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni) ;
```

Is likely where you have to go to do this, but tooltips on the control box, as is title font, colors, and the like, are system-wide settings.

Plus which, unless you have a really compelling reason for doing this, I would not bother.

If you figure it out, please post it. It will at least satisfy curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Return other HITTEST code in `WM_NCHITTEST` than `HTCLOSE, HTMINIMIZE` etc. (for example +0x80 for all types of caption buttons). In `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`, `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` etc. return correct HITTEST code before `DefWindowProc`. **Do not forget to add your own tooltips.**

It should work because Windows doesn't show tooltips for not known objects.